# Is there any form or aspect of Lord Shiva as Lord of speech or knowledge except Lord dakshinamurthy?

Tags: shiva, knowledge

Is there   any aspect or form of  Lord Shiva which  is related to knowledge and speech apart from Lord Dakshinamurthy ?

Answer (score 3):

**Summary: First some Vocabulary**

1. In Vedas Vāk = Speech. Any Speech/sound? No, that which is Akshara. Akshara = that which doesn't deplete, hence is eternal resonance. The entire creation is resonance. All Veda mantras are constructed of Aksharas. Hence Vedic samans are called Anu**Vāk**am.
2. Mantra = Anu**vāk**am chanted based on its meter to invoke certain resonance/vibration/Deva.
3. The primordial sounds are Aaaa + Ouuu + Ummm = AUM. These 3 sounds don't need the tongue to be twisted. All sounds are a modification of these 3.
4. Utmost importance is given to Speech (Vāk) as there are serious consequences to improper speech/chant. That is why one who chants Vedic Mantras has to mind their speech since such tendencies might reflect during Yajñá.
5. What is the purpose of Vāk? it is to sacrifice. Creation is Yajñá and we ourself is the final sacrifice.
6. So the question is? Who is the lord of Vāk, who is the lord of all the Speech and the knowledge of all Yajñá, and all the sacrifice associated with these Hymns? Who becomes the controller of this Vāk? Who is the one who enforces Vāk? What happens if Vāk is not pronounced properly? Who becomes the final sacrifice to this Vāk? With whom will the creation unfold and came the Aksharas (eternal sounds) and Gayatri?
7. What is the final achievement of all Yajñá through Vāk and Sacrifice of oneself? Its amṛta? So who holds amṛta?
8. Is Vedic exploration for casual reading? No, misinformation and false conclusions will lead to a waste of one's life and its limited time to have been born as the most evolved consciousness on the planet.
   This is what we are going to cover in our details next.

**Details:** Let's start with 3 references which should answer the first part of the questions about speech (Vāk).

> Rudra is gātha-patim = resort to all hymns/songs and he is medha-patim = the resort of Yajñá/Sacrifice/Oblations
> --Rig Vedā 1.43

> Thou, Oh Agni, art Rudra, the Asura of the mighty sky Rudra, lord of
> the sacrifice
> --Kṛṣṇa Yajur Vedā Taittirīya Saṃhitā 1.3.14, 1.4.11

> Thou art the beginning and thou art the end of the Vedas, thou art the
> Gāyatri and thou art OM. Thou art the fire upon which the sacrificial
> butter/ghee is poured. Thou art he who pours the ghee. Thou art he in
> honor of whom the ghee is poured, thou art the butter itself that is
> poured. Thou art those section of Brahmanas that are called
> Trisuparna, thou art all the Vedas, thou art the section called
> Śatarudrīya in the Yajushes/Yajur. Thou art holiest of holies,
> auspicious of auspicious things. Thou animatest the inanimate body.
> Thou art the Chit that dwell in the human form.
> -- Mahābhāratam Moksha Dharma Parva Section 285

**What is the proof of the above Statements?**

Agni is the Great Source, Agni is Vāk and the one to recite the Vedic Mantra (anu**vak**am) RV1.1.1, Agni is speech since He is a celestial priest (Hotr) who recites the hymns RV1.1.1, He is the transmitter of Sacrifice of Yajñá (medha) RV1.38,5.60, and the deliverer of Soma. Then who is the lord or hymns, and the lord of Medha and lord of Soma? It is Rudra, as He is gātha-patim and medha-patim RV1.43 and brahmānaspatim, **the lord of knowledge (omniscient) RV1.38.13**. Vājasaneyi Saṃhitā also describes the title Pashunapati as the “Lord of Sacrifice of Cattle”; here Sacrifice of Cattle means to donate cattle as Dakshina during Yajñás like Rājasuya.

**Knowledge:** This is the second part of the question.

> Veda Vyāsa says: The foremost one of all Devas/Gods, that destroyer of
> Daksha’s Yajñá, that divine lord having a bull as His sign, became
> gratified with the Devas. He is Rudra, He is Śiva, He is Agni, He is
> everything, and *He hath knowledge of everything*. He is Indra, He is
> the wind/Vayu, He is the twin Ashvins, He is the lightning. He is
> Bhava, He is Parjanya, He is Mahādeva, He is sinless (untouched by
> karma-cause-and-effect). He is the Moon/Soma, He is īśhana, He is
> Surya, He is Varuna. He is Kāla, He is Antaka, He is Mrityu, He is
> Yama. His terrible forms are Agni, Viśnu, and Surya. His auspicious
> forms are the water, light, and the Moon. Whatever is highly mysterious
> in the several branches of Vedās, in the Upaniṣhads, in the Puráńas,
> and in those sciences/Śāstra that deal with the soul/jiva-ātmān, is
> that God, viz., Maheswara. That God is again without birth.
> --- Mahābhāratam, Drona Parva – Narayanastra-mokshana Parva Section 203

**Is the Above Backed by Vedas?**

Here is the powerful sloka from Yajur Veda that answers your question.

> "Ishana Sarvavidyanam Ishwara Sarvabhutanam, Brahmadhipati,
> Brahmanodhipati, Brahma Shivo me Astu Sada Shiv Om" It's Lord Ishana
> who is the one to be worshipped for all
> knowledge/intelligence/Intellect.
>
> To the one with a joyful/peaceful heart, we want to declare to Rudra, to
> the **conscious knower, the most bountiful**, the mightiest, in order that
> Aditi would hold/sing (and bring forth) Rudriya on our behalf and on
> behalf of all creatures, in order that **knowledge** (cow), that
> Mitra-Varuna and that Rudra would wake us all to awareness; to this we
> all agree/conclude.  Rig Veda 5.41.11, 1.43.2
>
> यो देवानां प्रभवश्चोद्भवश्च विश्वाधिपो रुद्रो महर्षिः।हिरण्यगर्भं
> जनयामास पूर्वं स नो बुद्ध्या शुभया संयुनक्तु॥ He is (यो) the
> creator/source (प्रभव) of the emergence (उद्भवः) of all
> Deva’s/Divinity (देवा+नां) and the highest of Rishis (महर्षिः) and the
> supreme owner over entirety ( विश्व+अधिपो ). He who is the cause of
> time/and the emergence (जनया+अमस/जनयाम्+आस) of the brilliant/golden
> womb which is the source of creation (हिरण्यगर्भं), prior (पूर्वं) to
> celestial heavens and us (स – नो) and the one only (शुभया) to
> bestow/endow (संयुनक्त+ उ) **knowledge and intelligence** (बुद्ध्या)
> Please note: जन = people or production, जनया = leading man/mankind
> andअमस = time, but जनयामस can also be broken as जनयाम्+आस wherein
> जनयाम् = “cause of birth”.  Svetasvatara Upaniṣhad 3.2

Is it just Rudra who is the Lord of Knowledge?

**Maruts**:, the children of Rudra, are addressed with the three titles vidatheṣu ā-bhuvaḥ (born in knowledge), mahiṣāsaḥ māyinaḥ:citra-bhānavaḥ (the makers of māyā and of clear vision/light) and pra-cetasaḥ viśva-vedasaḥ (conscious & omniscient) RV1.64.6-10. Sukla Yajur Vedā Kanda 7.2 Brahmāṇa 1 narrates the story of the dual divinities Soma-Rudra who are the dispellers of darkness because Soma is Andhaḥ, meaning remover/dispeller RV1.122,2.33.7 and Rudra becomes **Andhasaspati (the lord of Soma)** meaning the Lord of dispeller of darkness because he holds knowledge and the final Amruta. They destroyed the asura Svarbhānu, who created darkness by obstructing the Sun. Similarly, they dispel the darkness in people and allow the brilliance to shine forth TS4.5.10. Maruts are addressed as the children of Pṛśni (Vedic cow of knowledge). The Rig Vedā also addresses the Maruts as vidatheṣu ā-bhuvaḥ, meaning born in knowledge, and brahmānaspathim, meaning lord/abode of knowledge RV1.38.13. Brahmānaspathim is a very unique title in the Vedās assigned to a separate class of Divinities. Sri Aurobindo defines brahmāna as the Vedic Aksharas (word) and among all Aksharas “अ/a” is considered the foremost, hence AUM begins with अ. In Śrīmad Bhagavādgita Śrī Kṛṣṇa says “Among words I am the word अ“. Panini, the author of Sanskrit Grammar says, Maruts are Akshara of Varnamala (an eternal string of sounds), and Sukla Yajur Vedā Śatarudrīya explains how Rudra and Gayatri Akshara emerged from Yagna. Sri Aurobindo includes both Brihaspati and Brahmā as brahmānaspathim. T.V. Kapali Sastry, renowned student of Sri Aurobindo and Vedic commentator, says Ganapati – “Lord of all Ganas/Maruts” – is that brahmānaspati. Interestingly, the Rig Vedā titles Viṣṇu as Evaya Marut RV5.87, meaning the “fastest Marut” who leads the Maruts into battle. This is a very interesting linkage of titles, like puzzles that fit together. RV5.58 confirms that Maruts are Ganas.

**Path of Yama:** there is a unique hymn that defines the word immortal on a different plane, the “Path of Yama“, and the home to the Supreme Truth (ṛta). This knowledge is held by Rudra. Liberation is not an act or a goal, it is to realize the true nature of the self that is superimposed with a cloud of misinformation called Avidya. Andhasah is the “remover/dispeller of A:vid” through knowledge (Vid). **But knowledge of what? It is the knowledge of the true nature of the self.**

> यद्यू॒यं पृ॑श्निमातरो॒ मर्ता॑सः॒ स्यात॑न ।स्तो॒ता वो॑ अ॒मृतः॑ स्यात् ॥
> 1.38.4 Though you (यद्यू॒यं), who were born to Prishni (पृ॑श्नि :मातरो॒ = cow of knowledge), are mortal (मर्ता॑सः॒), those who sing
> your hymns become immortal (not physical immortality, but a state of
> eternal consciousness: satyam. This hymn is explained in detail in
> Satarudriya Yagna later in Sukla Yajur Veda)
>
> मा वो॑ मृ॒गो न यव॑से जरि॒ता भू॒दजो॑ष्यः । प॒था य॒मस्य॑ गा॒दुप॑ ॥1.38.5
> For you (वो॑) one will not (मा ) become (भू॒द) negligible (अजो॑ष्यः)
> like a wild beast (मृ॒गो) or a pasturage cattle (यव॑से) Those who
> invoke you (जरि॒ता) attain (गा॒दु) the path (प॒था) of Yama (य॒मस्य॑).
> Note: Yama here is not the Puráńic identity of physical death, but the
> guardian of highest truth (satyam)
>
> pra-jāḥ amrtasya = immortals possessing the elixir (amṛta); parasmin
> dhāman ṛtasya = home to the highest truth || RV 1.43
>
> एवा बभ्रो वृषभ चेकितान यथा देव न हृणीषे न हंसि । हवनश्रुन्नो रुद्रेह
> बोधि बृहद्वदेम विदथे सुवीराः ॥ Certainly (एवा ), oh mighty
> chief/overlord (वृषभ ) with tawny/reddish hue (बभ्रो ), henceforth we
> proclaim (यथा ) **the all-knowing/omniscient Divine** (चेकितान देव),
> forgive us/not punish us (न हृणी), be not angry (न हंसि ), hear our
> oblation (हवनश्रुन्न) and direct us on this occasion (विदथ), oh
> powerful (बृहद्व) **Rudra of perfect wisdom/speech** (बोधि), bless us with
> noble and heroic successors (सुवीरा) || 2.33.15
>
> Rig Vedā 1.38/43, 2.33

**The Enforcer, Punisher, and Authoritarian to all Vāk**

Hymns sing to Rudras and Maruts as Earth-shaking clans feared by all lokas and are the only Divinities feared greatly by Rishis. Since the Vedās revolve around Yajñá, the aspect of fear is seen in the discipline, devotion, and secrecy of the Yajamana and Adhvaryu towards their Dikṣhā (initiation and sanctity), meaning the one hosting the Yajñá and the one performing/chanting the mantras in proper way (Ardhaka), else Rudra brings forth His wrath and consumes themTS1.6.7. Both sages and commoners feared the wrath of Rudras, but they knew that Rudras were not malicious. They understood the compassionate hand of the Rudras, hence they reached out to Rudras for protection, medicines, health, boons to bear children, boons to get a loving spouse, for wealth and prosperity VS3.57-59 like the hymn that says “Oh Rudra, harm us not, and abandon us not” RV7.46.5. But one has to ask, why Rudra? Why not Indra or Agni or Soma? Let’s see a few such examples of his fearful aspect of Rudra when it comes to Yajñá by traversing Atharva Veda to Yajur and finally to Rig Veda:

> अस्त्रा नीलशिखण्डेन सहस्राक्षेण वाजिना । रुद्रेणार्धकघातिना तेन मा सम्
> अरामहि ॥11.2.7 Oh Rudra (रुद्र), with powerful/swift/impetuous (वाजिना
> ) mighty weapons (अस्त्र), with dark hair and chest (शिखण्ड) (or)
> Bluish-Black turf ((नील +शिख), thousand eyes (सहस्राक्ष ) (or)
> dwelling in thousand places (सहस्र + क्षेण ), and inflictor/slayer
> (घातिन्) of Ardhaka (अर्धक), in this way (तेन ) one who alters
> (altering) and is improper (अराम ) chants the mantras (अर्धक) Please
> note: Ardhaka (अर्धक) means improper utterance of Vedic mantras.
> शिखण्ड = Chest and शिख = Turf at the crown of the head. सहस्र + क्षेण
> = thousand places. सहस्राक्ष = thousand eyes. क्षयण  = destruction and annihilation
>
> यो अन्तरिक्षे तिष्ठति विष्टभितो ऽयज्वनः प्रमृणन् देवपीयून् । तस्मै नमो
> दशभिः शक्वरीभिः ॥11.2.23 The one who (यो ) dwells and establishes
> oneself firmly (तिष्ठति + विष्टभित) among the sky (अन्तरिक्षे )
> destroys (प्रमृण) those who do not-sacrifice/insulting Divinities
> (अ-यज्वन् – देवपीयून् ) salutation and homage (नमो ) to the
> anger/fierce one (तस्मै ) we sign thy with ten (दशभिः ) hymns of
> Śākvara-Sāman (शक्वरीभिः ) अन्तरिक्षे = intermediator regions between
> Earth and Heavenly realms
>
> भव राजन् यजमानाय मृड पशूनां हि पशुपतिर् बभूथ । यः श्रद्दधाति सन्ति
> देवा इति चतुष्पदे द्विपदे ऽस्य मृड ॥11.2.28 Oh Bhava (भव ) you are the
> ruler/king (राजन् ) be gracious/favorable, pardon/spare (मृड ) towards
> the one hosting the Yagna (यजमानाय ) especially which donating cattle
> as a sacrifice (पशूनां ) especially you are the one to reach (बभूथ )
> being the lord of cattle (पशुपतिर् )| those who (यः ) have faith in
> the divine (श्रद्दधा श्रद्-दधान देवा ) view graciously (सन्ति) thus on
> (इति ) our four-legged (चतुष्पदे ) and two-legged (द्विपदे ) Please
> note: Yajamāna = the host of the ceremony, Adhvaryu = the one making
> oblations
> ~Atharva Veda 11.2.7/23

All the above concludes the relationship with Rudra and Speech and his role in enforcing Vak during Yajna. Below is a more detailed explanation for explorers to understand how Rudra is associated with Amruta and Gayatri and his rule in controlling Vak.

---------------------## Further details for explorers ##--------------------

Let’s visit one of the long-lost Vedic Shaka, the Katha Shaka which gave forth Katha Upanishad. Katha Shaka has its own Saṃhitās, Brahmana, and Aranyaka which many like the German researcher Michael Witzel conclude to be earlier than the Tairtreya Shaka of Yajur Veda. Like any Aranyaka, it primarily revolves around a particular aspect of Yajñá, so Katha Aranyaka too revolves around the concept of Pravargya which is a Soma ritual. As Michael Witzel says:

As an Aranyaka, it contains the secret doctrine of its particular Veda School (Sakha) and has to be studied in the wilderness (aranya). In the Katha Aranyaka, this is the Pravargya, a ritual in which a blazing clay vessel (mahavira) is identified with the Sun and Rudra Mahavira. This ritual also aims at giving the sponsor of the ritual (Yajamana) a new, heavenly body. This is established by multiple Upanishad-like identifications between various entities of the microcosm (man), ritual (Yajna), and macrocosm.

Please note: this heavenly body is a subtle body to ascend to the heavens (sargo vai loka auttaravedikas III 233: 91.1-2)

An Aranyaka usually contains, as its nucleus, the most dangerous ritual held in the highest esteem in a particular branch of the Veda. In the Rig Veda Aranyaka, it is the Mahavrata ceremony, the culmination of the one-year gavam ayana Sattra ritual. In the Yajur Veda, however, it is the Pravargya ritual that is given this kind of special attention.

One of the foremost features of the Pravargya ritual is its dangerous appearance as a glowing vessel identified with the Sun and with Rudra Mahavira (II 89,II 100, III 207, 233, 238). The vessel is connected with Rudra, as it is baked by the sun (II 22, CF. II 89) udvāsana of the utensil takes place in the shape of the Sun (II151-54) further, the heated vessel is round like the Sun and glows like it. The red-hot vessel threatens all beings and even Heaven and Earth. Special protection is necessary for the priest (II 80sqq., II 180, 182-183), for the yajamāna (III 150, 173-76, etc.), for his wife (III 207, 177), even for the further offspring of the yajamāna (II 38, III 207), which otherwise would be born blind.

There also is a whole section on expiating (prayāŚcitti), aiming at the protection of the yajamāna from Rudra (III 235 sqq). The yajamāna retains long life when atoning for an accidental boiling over of the gharma vessel, or when atoning for thunder (sorrow), rain falling during the Pravargya ritual (hitting by a vajra), or setting of the Sun (back luck) while the Pravargay still is underway.

> A priest (brahmana) who wants to spoil his own yajamāna for one reason
> or the another just has to alter one syllable…. Even the smallest
> mistake in ritual might lead to disaster: if certian mantras would be
> said loudly, Rudra would kill the yajamāna’s cattle (II 128A, cf. III
> 229). Katha Aranyaka, Harvard Oriental Series 65, Michael Witzel

In the Katha Aranyaka’s Pravargya ritual (Yajñá) the vessel (kalasha) used is called the Mahavira which is Identified with the brilliance of the Sun and Rudra as Rudra-Mahavira and so have to be performed very carefully after extended teachings and diksha (initiation and sanctity). Even during the Yagna any mistakes or mishaps have to be atoned else Rudra becomes the punisher, and can become Yama (death).

So, coming to our question, why Rudra? Because Rudra punishes Ardhaka (improper chanting) of Vedic Mantra and the sanctity of sacrifice of Yajñá and Divinities? Well the same Atharva Veda Chapter 11.2.17 in its very beginning answers this question and is well justified in Rig Veda 10.125.6

> सहस्राक्षम् अतिपश्यं पुरस्ताद् रुद्रम् अस्यन्तं बहुधा
> विपश्चितम्।मोपाराम जिह्वयेयमानम् ॥AV 11.2.17 Oh Rudra (रुद्र),
> thousand-eyed (सहस्राक्षम्) overseeing all /all-seeing through and
> through/directly (अति + पश्यसि + पुरस्तात्), at the end of our Yagna’s
> chanting Anuvākam (अस्य) Oh Multifold (बहुधा) wise (विपश्चित्) with
> prudent tough/divine speech ( जिह्व) gone after (येय) even and
> respectful ( मानम् ) Atharva Veda 11.2.17

Now, let’s evaluate Rudra’s divine speech aspect with Rig Veda.

> अहं रुद्राय धनुरा तनोमि ब्रह्मद्विषे शरवे हन्तवा 10.125.6 I (अहं) (Vac
> the divine speech) (अहं) Rudra’s (रुद्राय) Bow (धनुरा) bend/stretch
> the bowstring (तनोति) towards those who hostile to the sacred
> knowledge (ब्रह्म – द्विष्) swiftly (शर – वेग) to eliminate/kill
> (हन्तव्य) Rig Veda Mandala 10.125.6

The aspect of Rudra synonymous with weeping/roaring comes from the event in Taittirīya Saṃhitā 1.5.1 wherein all the knowledge and thoughts and riches were placed in Agni by the Devas in anticipation of a confrontation with the Asuras. Later, to recover their knowledge and thoughts, they harassed Agni – who wept and roared in anger and anguish. Hence, Agni becomes Rudra. As Agni restored this knowledge back to the Devas, Prajāpati, Manu and many cosmic phenomena like metals and seasons came into being. Further prosperity was bestowed upon all when the fire of Agni was re-established, hence Rudra is called “The Intelligence/Wise”AV11.2.17; similarly, Adityas are called “The Brilliance” KYV4.4.1,5.3.6. In this way, the concept of Rudra enters Agni and, at times, Agni becomes Rudra. We keep seeing the contradictions of Rudra. ‘Rud’ means weep/cry/roar, Rudra as defined by Br̥hadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad 3.9.4 is the one who causes us to weep, which is his feared aspect. In contradiction, all three profound commentators Sāyaṇācārya, Bhattabhaskara, and Abhinavasankara defined Rudra asरुदं द्रावयतीति इति रुद्र, meaning the one who removes the cause of our grief is Rudra. These 3 aspects of Rudra (Cry, makes us cry, and removes our cries) is perfectly captured in Mahābhāratam Itihāsa Harivamsha Parva Section 2.74 in which Sri Krishna says: “रुद्रो देव त्वं रुदनाद् रावणाञ्च रोरुयमाणो द्रावणाच्चवातिदेवः” meaning “oh divine Rudra it’s your cry, makes other cry and removes our cry”

**Amṛta**

They possess amṛta and medicines – especially Varuna, who is addressed as the Physician, just like Rudra is called the Divine PhysicianVS16.5. They are also addressed as those with knowledge and intelligence KYV4.4.1,5.3.6 – like the Maruts, who are born in knowledge, and brahmāspati, lord of wisdomRV1.38.13. They are the Asuras of Heavens and are ugrā (terrible/fierce), yet benignant and benevolent.

**Conclusion:**

> tavyase = mighty/strong Shamtamam Hruday = pleasant or beneficent
> heart gātha-patim = resort to all hymns/songs medha-patim = the resort
> of Yajñá/Sacrifice/Oblations śam-yoḥ sumnam = bliss/ānandam pra-jāḥ
> amṛtasya = immortals family possessing the elixir (amṛta) parasmin
> dhāman ṛtasya = home to the highest truth (ṛtasya) Please Note: Both
> terms “ṛtasya” and “amṛtasya” are synonymously used, soma is also used
> as its replacement occasionally. Rig Vedā 1.43

**The birth of Rudra and Gāyatrī**
Now, let us look at a metaphysical event of Prajāpati’s Yajñá from Sukla Yajur Vedā Śatapatha Brāhmaṇa Kanda 6 Brahmāṇa 3 (6.1.3.10-17):
In the beginning, Prajāpati was alone. He desired “may I multiply”. Upon His practicing austerity, there emerged fumes called Tapo:dhuma, from which came water. Water wished to flourish, upon austerity came foam; foam wished to flourish and upon austerity came clay. In this way each desired to be more and so performed austerity in the following order: water > foam > clay > sand > pebbles > stone > metal ore > gold > Akṣarā (imperishable syllables/sounds). Since this bloomed into eight-folds, the 8-syllable Gāyatrī emerge. All these became the foundation for Bhumi, which spread out (prath), hence became Pṛthvī. All continued their austerity for a Sāṃvatsara, meaning one year, and upon its dawn (Uṣas/Auṣasī) arose a child, meaning the union of Sāṃvatsara and Uṣas gave birth to a child. Upon birth, this child cried (arodīt); Prajāpati held this child and said “my son you are Rudra” (the first roar/sound). This is why Rudra is the primordial roar. Hence, please note that Rudra didn’t come as the boy, this boy was called Rudra. This boy could not be contained and wished to encompass everything and so said, “with my name I have to become greater” and asked for another name.
Prajāpati said “you are Sarva” and so the water became him, the boy grew in greatness and kept asking for more names.
He was named Paśūpati, from him emerged flora/fauna.
He was named Ugra (the fierce one), Vayu/Wind/Air became him.
He was named Aśani, lightning became him and so did thunder.
He was named Bhava, the rain became him and the Divinity of rain is Parjanya.
He was named Mahādeva, the highest Divinity, and the moon (Soma) became him; hence He, Mahādeva with a moon on his head.
He was named īśhana (the authority/the ruler), the Sun became him.

Please Note: Rudra here is the Agni itself. And Aśani the thunder becomes the power of Indra. Mahabharatam 7.175.96 specifies the weapon/missile of Rudra as “aṣṭacakrāṃ mahāghorāmaśaniṃ rudranirmitām“. The Samhita portion of Atharva Vedā 15th Kanda 18th Prayāya, known as Vrātyas Suktam state 7 of the above title, and the only name missing is Aśani, as if Aśani is centered among the 7. Kṛṣṇa Yajur Vedā Taittirīya Saṃhitā 4.5.5 use the same names except for Aśani, so these titles are not new, nor limited to Brahmāṇa section. When this nameless boy entered all aspects of creation and became creation itself. A much detailed event can be seen in the upcoming event of Śatarudrīya.

The full research article can be found by searching in Google "Sanatanadhara Śiva / Rudrā across Vedās to Itihāsa"

RV = Rig Vedā Saṃhitā, KYV = Kṛṣṇa Yajur Vedā, TS = Kṛṣṇa Yajur Vedā Taittirīya Saṃhitā, VS = Sukla Yajur Vedā Vājasaneyi Saṃhitā, TA = Kṛṣṇa Yajur Vedā Taittirīya Āraṇyaka, AV = Atharva Veda, AB = Aitareya Brahmāṇa, KA = Kaṭha Āraṇyaka, SB = Śatapatha Brahmāṇa, TB = Kṛṣṇa Yajur Vedā Taittirīya Brahmāṇa, MS = Maitrāyaṇī Saṃhitā

PS: Among the Svayambhu Kshetras the 18th position is Kedara and the name of deity is Ishana. So you have to find out the culture and traditions of this Kshetra (temple) and learn any karmic activity as your worship. [image]

Comment: It's informative, but it seems that the answer to the question doest exist or is not highlighted properly.

Comment: Sure will go over and try to trim. Unfortunately, the context had to be built up.

Comment: Done, updated the post, and sectioned it for short readers vs detailed readers.

Comment: Yes now it looks good.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. But can you point out any specific deity related to Lord Shiva which can be worshipped for intellect apart from Lord dakshinamurthy ?

Comment: @Tyagi Sure that is actually simple. Here is the powerful sloka from Yajur Veda that answers your question. 
"Ishana Sarvavidyanam Ishwara Sarvabhutanam, Brahmadhipati, Brahmanodhipati, Brahma Shivo me Astu Sada Shiv Om"
It's Lord Ishana who is the one to be worshipped for all knowledge/intelligence/Intellect.

Comment: @SanatanaDhara how to pray Lord Ishana for knowledge, intellect?

Comment: @Tyagi why are you trying to find, Shiva avatar for intellect, knowledge, apart from Dakshinamurthy?.

Comment: @ hindukid Well, I am trying to find a tantric form of Lord Shiva as Lord speech because I think that it will be easier to please ?!

Comment: @HinduKid Here is a link about Ishana https://www.astroved.com/astropedia/en/gods/ishana
How to pray Lord Ishana? You have to learn Tantric Kriyas. There are many but are very difficult to find a Guru. The only person who is tantric is Sadhguru (Isha Foundation). Please learn a kriya from his tantric list and hopefully, you can get a Bhairavi Yantras for your worship. You can find his kriyas at this link. But I suggest you read Vijñāna-bhairava-tantra and Shiva Sutras to get an idea of how to implement worship/sadhana.  https://www.innerengineering.com/program-locator

Comment: @HinduKid Among the Svayambhu Kshetras the 18th position is Kedara and the name of deity is Ishana. So you have to find out the culture and traditions of this Kshetra (temple) and learn any karmic activity as your worship. I will attach the image of many post as it cant add to this comment.